# Azure Resource Graph KQL - filter virtual machines having tags with given prefixes

Tags: azure, tags, virtual-machine, kql, kusto-explorer

We have a lot of virtual machines that we create in azure. Each virtual machine has tags. Keys for some of these tags are dynamically constructed. Such keys have a fixed prefix and a dynamic suffix. We wanted a way to filter all virtual machines which have 2 or more keys with given prefixes.

Consider the following Virtualmachines:

- VM1: {name: "vm-1", tags: {"bingo-1":1, "tringo-2":1, "key1": "value1"}}
- VM1: {name: "vm-1", tags: {"tringo-2":1, "key2": "value2"}}
- VM1: {name: "vm-1", tags: {"bingo-1":1, "key3": "value3"}}

Expected Output: `vm-1` as that is the only VM which contains both the tag-key-prefixes.

Attempt:
I got this working but this does not seem to be optimal as it calls bag_keys function twice.

```
resources
 | where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'
 | where resourceGroup =~ 'test-resource-group'
 | where bag_keys(tags) hasprefix "bingo-"
 | where bag_keys(tags) hasprefix "tringo-"
 | project name
```

This works as expected but at the cost of invoking bag_keys twice. Is there a more idiomatic and optimal way to achieve the same without calling bag_keys twice?

Comment: Not as efficient as checking the prefix but what about using **matches regex "^(bingo|tringo)-.*"** ?

Comment: I thought of using this but this will result in listing vm's which have either of bingo or tringo. What i want is it should filter the vms which have both bingo and tringo. Unless it is used as follows: 
resources
 | where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'
 | where resourceGroup =~ 'test-resource-group'
 | where tags matches regex "bingo-.*"
 | where tags matches regex "tringo-.*"
 | project name

This will work but i do not see much benefit here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using two `where` operators, firstly I included
[mv-expand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mvexpandoperator) operator to join tags into one record and then used an `and` to check and filter the tags of both prefixes to optimize your code.

```
resources
| where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'
| where resourceGroup =~ '<resourcegroup>'
| mvexpand tags
| extend tagKey = tostring(bag_keys(tags)[0])
| extend tagValue = tostring(tags[tagKey])
| where tagKey hasprefix "creat"  and tagKey hasprefix "cr"
| project name, tags, tagKey, tagValue
```

**Update:**

As given in comments, You can use `extend` operator. It creates a new column that contains all the keys in the tags object in this way.

```
extend tagKeys = bag_keys(tags) 
| where tagKeys hasprefix "bingo-" and tagKeys hasprefix "tringo-"
```

[image]

Refer resource graph explorer query [article](https://www.blueboxes.co.uk/working-with-tags-in-azure-resource-graph-explorer) by @John Kilmister for more related query samples.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This query does not work. Reason: mv-expand will create one row per tag. This means that if the VM has 3 tags then 3 rows will be created. Therefore once you apply the filter then it will apply it on each row and therefore you will never be able to apply more than one filter in conjunction as it will not yield any result.

Comment: Can you try with `extend` operator in that case! It creates a new column that contains all the keys in the tags object in this way. @madhav
 `extend tagKeys = bag_keys(tags)
| where tagKeys hasprefix "bingo-" and tagKeys hasprefix "tringo-"`

Comment: Yes this works. If you can edit your original solution then i can mark it as an accepted solution